# How to clamp GeoJSON data format to terrain in Cesium Sandcastle?

Tags: javascript, geojson, cesiumjs, sandcastle, clamp

I have terrain view in Cesium Sandcastle and I have loaded roads data in GeoJSON format, they are lines. I want to clamp them on terrain, like this example (in drop-down menu choose "Sample line positions and draw with depth test disabled") -> http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Ground%20Clamping.html&label=Tutorials
In the example, the line you see is defined within code, but I have data (roads) on my PC which is loaded in app. When loaded, roads are flat (under the terrain) and somehow I have to clamp them on terrain but don't know how.

I have tried using the existing code from the example but haven't succeed.

This is my code for now:

```
//Add terrain
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url : 'https://assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/v1/tilesets/world/tiles',
    requestWaterMask : true,
    requestVertexNormals : true
});
viewer.terrainProvider = cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes;
viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;

//Load data (roads)
var dataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('../../SampleData/ceste_rab_okvir.geojson');
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
```

I know there is [Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.clampToGround](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GeoJsonDataSource.html?classFilter=geoj#.clampToGround), but as I'm not a developer, I don't understand how to write it in my code.
Does anyone knows how to do it? Or maybe there is another way to clamp roads to terrain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. It should be written like this:

```
//Add terrain
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url : 'https://assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/v1/tilesets/world/tiles',
    requestWaterMask : true,
    requestVertexNormals : true
});
viewer.terrainProvider = cesiumTerrainProviderMeshes;
viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;

//Load data (roads)
Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.clampToGround = true;
var dataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('../../SampleData/ceste_rab_okvir.geojson');
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
```